# Help with combining sentences

Tags: grammar

Could you help me check whether my combined sentences are correct or not?

> She was carrying a tray.
>
> The tray was filled with cakes.
>
> The cake were homemade.
>
> They were very delicious.

1. She is carrying a tray **of** delicious homemade cake.
2. She is carrying a tray **filled with** delicious homemade cake.
3. She is carrying a tray **with** delicious homemade cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original sentences contain an error, prior to combining. This sentence contains an instance of disagreement between subject and verb number: one is singular, the other plural:

> The cake were delicious

The combined sentence uses the singular "cake", which means that you're treating "cake" as something uncountable. While this is possible and grammatically correct, it has a different nuance. Uncountable "cake" refers to an undifferentiated quantity of cake material, such as many cakes crumbled or mashed together, or simply a viewpoint of not caring about distinction between individual cakes (because there are so many, or because the perspective is one of indiscriminate consumption, or voluminous production, or something like that):

> Joe's stomach was so full of cake he could hardly move. That was the most cake he had ever eaten.
>
> Mom sure baked a heck of a lot of cake over the holidays last year.

A change to this nuance is inappropriate; the original sentences that are to be combined refer to a tray containing individual cakes.

The sentences are each a good combination of the originals if "cakes" is pluralized.

Comment: It's my error. I forgot to add an"s" after the cakes were delicious. So it should be "She is carrying a tray of delicious homemade cakes."right?

Comment: That is right. Or "filled with" or "with".

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one cake, then "cake" should be plural throughout. Besides that, all your examples look fine to me.

Comment: I agree that the sentences should be consistent throughout, but it's worth noting that _cake_ can be used as a mass noun: _She is carrying a tray of delicious cake_ can work even when the tray is filled with slices from two or three different cakes.

Comment: But only #2 carries through the *filled with* part.  So I think #2 is better than 1 and 3.

Comment: @J.R. Oh, absolutely. "She was carrying a tray filled with cake" and "She was carrying a tray filled with cakes" are both grammatically correct. My comment was just on consistency with the original sentences, not the grammatical correctness of the final sentences.